# Does max_replicas_per_node affect parallelism in update_config?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

### Problem

So far my docker-compse looks like this:

```
services:
  nodejs:
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: any
      placement:
        max_replicas_per_node: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
        delay: 10s
        order: start-first
```

On the first `docker stack deploy st` my stack looks like this (`docker stack ps st` modified to fit in):

```
ID NAME             IMAGE    NODE  DESIRED  CURRENT STATE            ERROR                           PORTS
py st_nodejs.1      :latest  dev   Running  Running 13 seconds ago
hq st_nodejs.2      :latest        Running  Pending 16 seconds ago   "no suitable node (max replica…"
```

Lets say I moved the `latest` tag in my registry and want to update my service with `docker-compse pull && docker stack deploy st`. Now my stack looks like this:

```
ID NAME             IMAGE    NODE  DESIRED  CURRENT STATE            ERROR                           PORTS
qh st_nodejs.1      :latest        Running  Pending 33 seconds ago   "no suitable node (max replica…"
py st_nodejs.1      :latest  dev   Running  Running 16 minutes ago
nw st_nodejs.2      :latest        Running  Pending 33 seconds ago   "no suitable node (max replica…"
hq  \_ st_nodejs.2  :latest        Running  Pending 16 minutes ago   "no suitable node (max replica…"
```

### Question

I think `max_replicas_per_node` is limiting the `update_config.parallelism` entry so the result is it can't start a new node, but I did not find any proof about my theory.

Am I right, and is there a better solution?

---

### Goals

1. I want to limit my service to one per node (for now because 2 core machines are to expensive).
2. But if there is one node joining the swarm, it should run one container (`replicas: 2` for having max two nodes in the swarm).
3. I also want updates to applied by first starting the new container and then killing the old one (`update_config.parallelism: 2`).

Comment: Looks like a bug you could post on github.com/moby/moby - the combination of "start-first" and max_replicas along with limited nodes blocks the update.

Comment: Ah ok my bad, I just found the issue describing my problem -> https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40797

Answer (score 1):

It [looks like](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26259#issuecomment-425994805) `max_replicas_per_node` is a hard limit:

> if you think that --max-replicas-per-node settings should be hard limit which cannot be exceed even on rolling upgrade

---

In my opinion, the best way seems updating the `replicas` when the swarm contains more than one node and keeping `max_replicas_per_node` equal (or greater) to `parallelism`:

##### `1` worker node

```
deploy:
  replicas: 1
  placement:
    max_replicas_per_node: 2
  update_config:
    parallelism: 2
    order: start-first
```

##### `n` worker nodes (`n>1`)

```
deploy:
  replicas: n
  placement:
    max_replicas_per_node: 2
  update_config:
    parallelism: 2
    order: start-first
```